# By registering always make uppercase the first letter of the login

Tags: login, user-registration

When a New User to register on my site ...

I would like that in your login, the first letter always be capitalized. ( uppercase letter )

Forcibly.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can possibly add a filter to [`sanitize_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_user) and return `ucfirst($username);`, I haven't tried it though to verify if it will work.

Comment: do you have any ideia about a code to do this? i'm not a programmer